# How to solve the issue that `git checkout <branch-name>` brings me a commit that was outdated?

Tags: git, github

I did `git clone` some 12 days ago, and then since then, I have updated or added a branch in that repo `foo` from upstream (where my repo was forked from GitHub).

But in that old directory, I could not even change to that branch at first.

And then, I did

```
git fetch --all
git checkout -b some-branch-name   # the  -b  is important or else it 
                                   #   thinks some-branch-name is a filename
```

and can switch to that branch. But when I `git log`, I am seeing the most recent commit that was 12 days ago.

How do I make it current?  If I `git clone` again from GitHub and `git checkout <some-branch-name>`, then I `git log` and will see commits done today instead of 12 days old.

But I don't want to have to set everything up again using `npm i` etc etc, so I would hope to have the old directory be able to see the current branch content.

Answer (score 0):

A branch name remembers some specific commit for you. A tag name does the same thing. The difference between the two (branch name vs tag name) is that Git, and Git users, are expected to *move* branch names to newer commits.

In your case, you would simply run:

- `git fetch` or `git fetch origin`: the `origin` part is the name of a *remote*, which is mainly just a short name for a URL.  This tells your Git to call up another Git—the Git you cloned from originally—and to bring in new commits that you do not already have.  It remembers where the *other* Git's branches are, using your *remote-tracking branch names*.  So if they have a branch named `master`, you get one named `origin/master`, which remembers where their Git's `master` was on the last `git fetch`.
- `git log` on the remote-tracking branch name(s): for instance, `git log origin/master` to see what is in `origin/master` after you have updated your `origin/master` from the other Git's `master`.
- `git merge` or `git rebase`: these merge with, or rebase (copy) your commits, on to some other branch, such as a remote-tracking branch.

If you create a *new* branch (as you did with `git checkout -b`), this new branch probably does not have an *upstream* setting.  You can choose one (and only one) of your remote-tracking branches to set as its upstream.  For instance, if your new branch `some-branch-name` should have `origin/master` as its upstream:

```
git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/master some-branch-name
```

Once you have set this, your Git knows that when you are on your `some-branch-name` branch, a plain `git merge` or `git rebase` should use your `origin/master` to do the merge or rebase.

Once you know how all this works, you can combine the `git fetch` command and the second (merge or rebase) command using the `git pull` convenience command.  I recommend delaying this until you are familiar with the individual commands.  Sometimes, the second command (of the two commands that `git pull` runs for you) *fails*.  When this command fails, you need to know what command you were running.  If you know only `git pull` you will not know what second command you were running!

Comment: the `-b` was not to create the branch here but to switch branch. Without the `-b`, it thinks `some-branch-name` is a filename, and keep on giving `error: pathspec 'some-branch-name' did not match any file(s) known to git.`

Comment: But `-b` *does* create a branch. For that matter, `git checkout master` in a new clone *also* creates a branch—it's just that it automatically creates one *from* `origin/master` with the new branch's upstream set to `origin/master`. This is a special case that `git checkout` implements: if you name a local branch that does not exist yet, it looks to see if it can create a local branch from one of your remote-tracking branches. If `some-branch-name` does not match exactly one remote-tracking branch name, Git cannot create the local branch using this short-cut.

Comment: hm... as it is right now, if it created a branch... then why is it showing the most recent commit as of 12 days ago? The bottom line is, how do I get it to show the commit as of today? (to make the directory current)

Comment: Once you are on a branch, that's *your branch* to do with as you will. If you wish to update your branch, you must tell Git to update your branch, as I said above.

Comment: how do I "update" the branch? I have `git fetch` and `git fetch --all`... so why is it not current? What do I need to do to "update"? As I said if I `git clone` again and switch to that branch, I see it all "updated". So why not that old folder?

Comment: As I said above, `git fetch` brings in the commits and updates your *remote-tracking* branches (but not *your* branches, those are *yours*). You must then run a second command, such as `git merge` or `git rebase`, to update your own branches. You can also create new branches or delete existing branches—all of these are *your* branches, as opposed to your remote-tracking branches, which are your Git's memory of some other Git's branches.

Answer (score 0):

`git checkout -b some-branch-name` creates a new branch `some-branch-name` from `HEAD` and then checks out the new branch. If `HEAD` points to the commit 12 days ago, the new branch points to this old commit too.

If a branch in the remote repo, which is the fork in your case, has been updated since your last clone. You could update the local corresponding branch:

```
git checkout <branch-name>
git fetch origin <branch-name>
git merge FETCH_HEAD
#Or use rebase. It depends on your workflow and strategy.
git rebase FETCH_HEAD
```

The `fetch-merge` is equivalent to `git pull origin <branch-name>`, and `fetch-rebase` to `git pull --rebase origin <branch-name>`, by default.

It doesn't matter if it has no upstream branch. If the local branch has no local new commits yet, or if it has but you think they can be abandoned, `git reset FETCH_HEAD --hard` is also okay.